# Area Under Curve - 1D Array (Java)

Tags: java, math, numerical-integration

I have a quick question, that in most languages (such as python) would be straightforward.

I am looking to obtain the integral (area of curve) from an 1D-array of fixed points. Java apparently has many numerical integration libraries, all of which seem to require a function (f {double(x)})  as input.

However I can not seem to find any which accommodate arrays (double []) such as [1,4,10,11]. I would be integrating over the entirety of the array (x values 1-n, where n represents the size of the array)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's not exactly hard to implement [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) for yourself...

Comment: Agreed, however I would prefer to utilize optimized libraries, based on the nature of the code which will be calling this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they expect functions because its normal to use them with a continuity.
Since you have only a different height every step (1,2,3,4...?) you have rectangles with triangles on top of them. the height of the triangles is the difference between the current height and the previous height. therefore the rectangle s height is the current pint height minus triangle height.
Write a function which calculates and adds both areas.
Do this for every point/item in your Array and you will get the integral of your "function".

EDIT: I wrote a little code. no guarantee, I just coded some easy to understand code of the idea of this integral prob. Further improvements have to be done.

```
    public static double getIntegralFromArray(double[] ar, double xDist)
    {
        double base = 0;
        double prev = 0;
        double triHeight = 0;
        double rectHeight = 0;
        double tri = 0;
        double rect = 0;
        double integral = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            triHeight=Math.abs(ar[i]-prev); // get Height Triangle
            tri = xDist*triHeight/2;    // get Area Triangle
            if(ar[i]<=prev){
                rectHeight = Math.abs(base-ar[i]); // get Height Rectangle
            }else {
                rectHeight = Math.abs(base-(ar[i]-triHeight)); // get Height Rectangle
            }
            rect = xDist*rectHeight;    // get Area Rectangle
            integral += (rect + tri); // add Whole Area to Integral
            prev=ar[i];
        }
        return integral;
    }

    double[] ar = new double[]{1,2,3,2,2,3,1,3,0,3,3};
    System.out.println(MyMath.getIntegralFromArray(ar, 1));

    Area under 'curve': 21.5
```

Comment: "and you will get the integral of your function" - Well, an approximation of the integral ...

Comment: Well I appreciate the effort put into the solution. While the intention of the question was to figure out how it was possible that no Java library contained a finite integral from an array, I will accept this answer until someone can point to an optimized version, Akin to (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) you can simply call below method to get area under a graph(approx.)

```
public static double trapz(double ar[],double xDist){
        if (ar.length==1 || ar.length==0)
            return 0;
        double integral=0;
        double prev=ar[0];
        for (int i=1;i<ar.length;i++)
        {
            integral+=xDist*(prev+ar[i])/2.0;
            prev=ar[i];
        }
        return integral;
    }
```